# How to allow specific domain name to access my domain?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this in my .htaccess

```
<Limit GET POST>
Deny from all

Allow from xxx.x.xxx.x
Allow from xxx.xx.xxx.x
Allow from xxx.xx.xx.x
</limit>
```

So I am good with this setup now I am allowing certain ip to access my server but now I need add another but I cannot get their ip address so I need to allow via their url. How can I accomplish this case?

for example I want `developer.paypal.com/(any)` to allow to access the php scripts in my server

Comment: What do you mean by `allow using their url`? This is URL on your web server right? Once you allow access to this URL **everyone** will be able to access this URL. Is that you want?

Comment: maybe it will help [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/allow-single-url/)

Comment: @anubhava , just edited my question. please see it again for better info. Thank you

Comment: @Prix, isn't possible to allow their domain name?

Comment: @Prix thanks, for the answer `Allow from bla.com` was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Allow from bla.com
```

Assuming that `bla.com` is the domain name and that it is properly assigned to the IP that is making the requests to your site.

If the IP is not properly assigned to that domain name or is dynamic you can use a different approach such as user and password authentication, and others available.